# What is the difference between a Helix antenna and a UFL one?

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna

I have bought a SIM800L, and I see two antennas:

- Connector UFL (IPX Antenna)
- Helix Antenna

What is the difference between these antenna?

Can I use both of them together?

[image: SIM800L components]

[image: SIM800L pins]

[image: SIM800L pins]

Answer (score 3):

U.FL is the connector; the antenna is printed on the attached PCB.

It depends on the design, but in general you'd use one or the other.  To design it to use both would be a lot of trouble just to increase the cost.  It's probably to give some flexibility in the way the module is integrated into the larger design.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the geometry of each define the optimal gain and beamwidth.

It's like asking I have 2 different reflectors with lenses for a bulb. Can I use them?

The datasheets can tell you best how to use them.  Helix antenna are very sensitive but when tuned give more gain and a narrow beamwidth for point-to-point long distance better performance.

Comment: [datasheet](https://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet_SIM800L.pdf) says: It is recommended that the GSM antenna and the BT antenna should be placed as far as possible.  The isolations of the three antenna should be bigger than 30db.| However this is not very clear how their impact will be. Are they useful to be used together. BTW, I am not sure if GSM and BT each refer to which antenna.